# Magento2, cleaning cache led to createApplication error

Tags: magento2, cache, deploy

Instead of running cache:clean I removed the folders from var directory, now I get error `index.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication` Even I can not deploy:content anymore :(

Comment: firstly try - setup:di:compile it will generate var directory again and then try static:content:deploy and cache:clean command may be it will solve the issue

Comment: it worked, tnx. Create answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to  try - **setup:di:compile** command it will compile whole code and  generate the var directory again.

and then try **static:content:deploy** and **cache:clean** **command** it will solve the issue